# Issue in removing Tags in HTML FIles using IPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, nsstring

In My Application I need to Read HTML Page. For That Purapose I am removing the HTML tags Using the below code.

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)htmlStr
 {
    NSRange r;
    while ((r = [htmlStr rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        htmlStr = [htmlStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    htmlStr=[htmlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"html update is %@",htmlStr);
    return htmlStr; 
}
```

I am Getting result removing all tags its works Fine. But **Now in My HTML page i need to read img Tag and their src element .** 
Is there any way t read specic tag complete info. 
Please any one Help in  this isse.

Thank In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [Link](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) will help check out the following method

> // Strips HTML tags & comments, removes extra whitespace and decodes HTML character entities.
>   
> - (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
>
> // Decode all HTML entities using GTM.
>   
> - (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
>
> // Encode all HTML entities using GTM.
>   
>  - (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
>
> // Minimal unicode encoding will only cover characters from table 
>   
> - (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities:(BOOL)isUnicode;
>
> // Replace newlines with `<br />` tags.
>   
> - (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
>
> // Remove newlines and white space from string.
>   
> - (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;

Comment: Thanks For Yor reply . But there is no for not removing specific tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-(void)myMethod
{


NSString* htmlStr = @"<some>html</string>";
NSString* strWithoutFormatting = [self stringByStrippingHTML:htmlStr];

 }

-(NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)str
 {
  NSRange r;
  while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location     != NSNotFound)
  {
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  }
  return str;
 }
```